# SQL Server query to find tables across all databases, that references a column in a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to find the tables from all the databases that references a column in a table in one of the database. Can anyone help me here?

Not sure how to proceed

Comment: Please don't tag both MySQL and SQL Server, they are very different things

Answer (score 1):

this should do, please see that i have used like operator (where col.name like '%COLUMN_NAME_HERE%'), so it will find matching patterns, if you want to find exact match then please use (where col.name = 'COLUMN_NAME_HERE')

```
select 
     schema_name(tab.schema_id) as schema_name
     ,tab.name as table_name
     , col.column_id,col.name as column_name
     , t.name as data_type, col.max_length, col.precision 
from sys.tables as tab 
    inner join sys.columns as col on tab.object_id = col.object_id
    left join sys.types as t on col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id 
where col.name like '%COLUMN_NAME_HERE%' 
order by schema_name,table_name, column_id*
```

Comment: About objects is *other* databases?